# Application hangs while getting a connection from a "stale connection pool"

Tags: java, swing, networking, connection, pool

I have written a java app which first creates a connection pool at startup and during each refresh, get a connection from the pool, use it, and then close it.The problem happens when I get disconnected from the network and the user presses the Refresh button. The application seems to go into a hung state (from my debug messages, it shows that it is waiting to get a connection from the pool, which it never gets). Is there anyway, I could timeout this request? I am new to java programming. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you use an [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) for your Swing GUI? Do not do long running tasks on the `EDT`, rather use [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) or Thread depending on whether any Swing components will be modified. This should be done using `SwingUtitlities.invokeXXX` or override `done()` of `SwingWorker`.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Running an "expensive" call on EDT would make the application "appear" as frozen. However, there are 2 things here:
1. The app indeed gets frozen (it does not eventually come out of this call of getting the connection)
2. I *have to* go for the EDT for this request as there is no meaning getting forward with the code unless I get this connection

Comment: That does not mean it should happen on the EDT. You can show a 'wait cursor', a progressbar, ... to inform the user you are waiting for a connection, and retrieve the connection on a background thread. This avoids that the application looks frozen, but the user still cannot continue

Comment: I understand the implication of running this call on EDT. However, I am still unclear on why it does not come out of this "eventually". (perhaps by throwing a sql error, which does happen for me if I was not connected to the network at the time of creating the connection pool, aka at startup). We cannot blame EDT to **actually** hang the application.

Comment: If the EDT is waiting for a connection, your application will remain frozen until that method returns. If you are in doubt where the application is stuck you can take a thread dump (using your IDE, using  jstack, using jconsole, ... )

Answer (score 0):

You could look at your `ConnectionPoolDataSource` implementation; it might have a way to reset the pool. I don't know a direct way to know if the network gets disconnected, but you do the reset in a `WindowAdapter` and just add a reset button.